# Any way to have one back office to administrate multipe sites in drupal?

Tags: multi-sites

I have two websites in one instance of drupal and I want to administrate this websites in one back office, any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the top answer to this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78328/does-drupal-support-multitenancy. Maybe it will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are looking for [Domain Access module](http://drupal.org/project/Domain):

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites such as:
>
> - example.com
> - one.example.com
> - two.example.com
> - my.example.com
> - thisexample.com <-- can use any domain string
> - example.com:3000 <-- treats non-standard ports as unique